# Separate data points into two classes with pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have some data points on the (x,y) field that are supposed to be cotegorised into two classes denoted here with X and O like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1 = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.4,0.7])
x2 = np.array([0.1,0.4,0.5,0.9,0.2,0.3,0.6,0.2,0.4,0.6])
c=np.array([ 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0 ])
plt.plot(x1[c==0], x2[c==0], 'bo')
plt.plot(x1[c==1], x2[c==1], 'rx')
```

Now I want to find a way so I can find the “best fitting curve” separating those like this
[image]

First I though maybe I try nearest neighbor method but I’ve been told it cannot apply here and that there’s a much simpler way to do it with an ANN maybe and using PyTorch but I can’t understand how.
Any ideas on what to use and/or how to do it and what should I check to estimate my accuracy?? There are too few points so what's the idea here??

Thank you everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be as a basic case and neural networks might be an overkill for this task. Also, if you later want to do some visualization as the one you posted, you should probably go for a more fundamental approach.

You can try Linear Classifiers(Support Vector Machines, Linear Regression and etc.)

Check the links below

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html